# how to run trigger after update table then running statement update in same table

Tags: mysql, trigger.io

I have table `machine` and I would like to create trigger, the condition is when table `machine` updates the trigger will be running script update table `machine` again where field `status_1` = '' `OR` `status_2` = ''

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_machine` AFTER UPDATE ON `machine`
FOR EACH ROW 
UPDATE `machine` 
SET `status_1`='disabled',`status_1`='disabled' 
WHERE `status_1`='' OR `status_2`=''
```

but the error say

## 1442 - Can't update table 'machine' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

but how can I still run this trigger?

Comment: you can't update the same table in the trigger

Comment: For your case, it will be much better to move these kind of logic/checking out of triggers. You could set `DEFAULT 'disabled'` for `status` columns and check empty inputs on program. Triggers and Stored Procedures for high-level checking inputs will take your application apart. Not recommended for security and software design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Trigger can't update another row of the same table.

A typical way to do this is to create a stored procedure that updates your table and then update other rows of the same table.

Comment: how is the script ?